# append data while double looping of record

Tags: java

I have data like given below.

```
11
13
15
17
25         
26
29
30
17  
25      
26
29
30
25      
26
29
30
25       
26
29
30
17
25
26
29
30 
17
19
```

In this data there are two groups of record (15,17) can occur only once at position only 3rd and 4th only. Second group is (25, 26, 29, 30) and can be occur multiple times.

Record 17 is like a break..after this new group starts and in that group multi subgroups(25,26,29,30) could be present.

I want to append two characters when ever a new group starts, and keep increment the subgroup if doesnt break by breaker record(17).

I hope its cleared.
My output data looks like this

```
11
13
1115
17
2125         
26
29
30
17  
3125      
26
29
30
n225      
26
29
30
n325       
26
29
30
17
4125
26
29
30 
17
19
```

tried so far..with this abstract code. But not able to handle subgroups with n character

```
int line=0
int seq =0


    if     (in.equal =15 or 25) {
            line++
            seq++
            context.line = line++  // variable to store line variable
            context.seq = seq++    // variable to store seq variable
            out = context.line+context.seq+in  // out is output record and in is input record mentioned in above data
            flag = 1
            }
    else  (if in.equal = 17 and flag = 1){
            flag = 0
            seq=0
           }
```

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: It's not clear as to what you want to achieve. You say that the record 15 and 17 can appear in line 3 or 4. But I see that they appear elsewhere too.

Comment: @VHS...As you can see record 15 is no where present in data except at position 3rd.  You can consider first group having record only 15 which can occur at position 3rd only and second group is (25,26,29,30)  can be occur multiple times after 3rd position.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the problem statement at all. I think all of us are having a hard time understanding this. Otherwise you would have seen a lot of comments or answers